# mostrar datos de un array en un tabla html (jquery, ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, json, array

tengo una ruta que segun un id me devuelve un array con informacion (en este ejemplo el id 5 tiene 2 asignaciones y dos detalles, concuerda bien con lo de la base de datos:

```
// 20210209132806
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/tec/mat/5

[
  {
    "asignacion": {
      "id": 7,
      "fecha_asignacion": "2021-02-08 18:34:24",
      "num_guia_despacho": 0,
      "tipo": "test-01",
      "tecnico_id": 5,
      "usuario_id": 1,
      "observaciones": "testing",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    "detalles": {
      "id": 2,
      "cantidad": 10,
      "material_id": 6,
      "asignacion_material_id": 7,
      "bodega_id": 1,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    "bodega": {
      "nombre_bodega": "Bodega Testing"
    }
  },
  {
    "asignacion": {
      "id": 8,
      "fecha_asignacion": "2021-02-09 11:19:20",
      "num_guia_despacho": 987,
      "tipo": "asrt",
      "tecnico_id": 5,
      "usuario_id": 4,
      "observaciones": "testing",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    "detalles": {
      "id": 3,
      "cantidad": 6,
      "material_id": 1,
      "asignacion_material_id": 8,
      "bodega_id": 2,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    "bodega": {
      "nombre_bodega": "Bodega Claro Sur"
    }
  }
]
```

ahora bien, necesito de ese array mostrar algunos datos en una tabla html simple. Tengo una funcion jquery:

```
$('#tecnico_id').on('change', function(){
        var id = $('select[name=tecnico_id]').val();
        $('#tecnico_id').val('');
        //console.log(bodega_id)
        $('#tecnico_id').val(id);

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ url('/tec/mat') }}"+`/${id}`,
            method:"get",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                var jdata = data;
                //console.log(data.datos);
                $("#cuerpo").html("");

                for(var i=0; i< jdata.data.asignacion.length[0]; i++){
                    var tr = `<tr>
                    <td>`+jdata.data.asignacion[i].fecha_asignacion+`</td>
                    <td>`+jdata.data.detalles[i].bodega_id+`</td>
                    <td>`+jdata.data.asignacion[i].num_guia_despacho+`</td>
                        </tr>`;
                    $("#detalles").append(tr)
                }

            }
        });


       });
```

cuando hago las pruebas me da el siguiente error en la consola y no trae ningun dato: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asignacion' of undefined

En mi controlador traigo la data con esta funcion:

```
public function getMaterialTecnico($id){
    $datos =[];
    $asignaciones = AsignacionMaterial::where('tecnico_id','=',$id)->get();
    foreach ($asignaciones as $asignacion){
        $datos[] = array(
        "asignacion" => $asignacion,
        "detalles" => $detalle = DetAsignacionMaterial::where('asignacion_material_id', $asignacion->id)->first(),
        "bodega" => $detalle = Bodega::select('nombre_bodega')->where('id', $detalle->bodega_id)->first()
        );
    }
    return $datos;
    //return response()->json([ 'datos' => $datos]);
}
```

No se que puede estar mal en el codigo...

Saludos a todos

Comment: Las llamadas **AJAX** esperan una salida por pantalla desde el servidor para recuperar los datos, por lo que en vez de hacer un `return $datos` deberías hacer algo como `echo json_encode($datos)` para transformar el `array` en un `string` con formato **JSON** y de esa manera recuperarlo en `success` de la llamada **AJAX**

Comment: con return json_encode($datos); pero aun no me muestra el error

Comment: Cambia **temporalmente** esto: `dataType: "json",` por esto: `dataType: "html",` y luego, haz una prueba de consola con esto exactamente: `console.log(data);` así podrás revisar en la consola lo que está respondiendo el servidor, al ponerle un dataType html no te dará error de validación. Generalmente con json ocurren estos errores cuando el servidor emite un json no válido, debido a que dejas escapar más salidas aparte del array, o porque algún dato dentro del array tiene problemas de codificación, produciendo un json inválido.

Comment: cambiado lo que me comentas en consola me imprime lo mismo

Comment: tengo la duda en el success: success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //console.log(data.datos);
                //$("#detalles").html("");
                for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){

                    var tr = `<tr>
                    <td>`+data.asignacion.fecha_asignacion+`</td>

                        </tr>`;
                    $("#detalles").append(tr)
                }

            }